# Laravel validation of spezific field/value

Tags: laravel, validation

i have a form field with two options:

```
{!! Form::select('pet',array('1'=>'Dog', '2'=>'Cat') ,null,['class'=>'form-text']) !!}
```

is there any way to validate this values via `$this->validate($request, [...])` or do i have to do this via `if` statement?

thanks for any sugestions.

Comment: did you try: $this->validate($request, ['pet' => 'required']); ? it should work

Comment: `$this->validate(request(), [
                'pet' => 'required'
            ]);` should do the trick.

Comment: it's my mistake. I have write this question wrong, that's because my bed english. I mean i will prevent that users will change the value in the web browser for example to another option '3'=>'Something else' and sent this into database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant prevent people edit the data

You have to validate the data once you have the request in you server

Could try like this:

```
$this->validate(request(), [ 
    'pet' => 'required|in:1,2' 
]);
```

so only if pet value is 1 or 2 will pass.
not tested but should work